# Rendering error for custom TextView

Tags: android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom text view class for specific font.

My class:`

```
public LobsterTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "lobster1_4.otf");
    this.setTypeface(face);
}

public LobsterTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "lobster1_4.otf");
    this.setTypeface(face);
}
```

}

my layout:

```
 <x.y.z.LobsterTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_mobile_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_large3"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent_3"
        android:text="Register with Pika" />
```

and error:` Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- io.pika.pike_store.utils.LobsterTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   at android.graphics.Typeface.createAssetUid(Typeface.java:219)   at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:193)   at io.pika.pike_store.utils.LobsterTextView.(LobsterTextView.java:22)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:197)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:902)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:854)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) Copy stack to clipboard  The LobsterTextView custom view has been edited more recently than the last build: Build the project.

**My code once run works fine.but this error always come in foreground when i come to layout file.**

How can i solve the problem?`

Answer (score 0):

public class PahariTextView extends TextView {

```
public PahariTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    applyCustomFont(context);
}

public PahariTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    applyCustomFont(context);
}

public PahariTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    applyCustomFont(context);
}

private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
    Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("fonts/quicksand_light.otf", context);
    setTypeface(customFont);
}
```

}

Comment: @pahari,thanks for the response pahari. still getting same problem,and there is no difference beetween your code and my code.

Comment: please describe in details

Comment: private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
    Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("fonts/quicksand_light.otf", context);
    setTypeface(customFont);

Comment: "lobster1_4.otf"    "fonts/lobster1_4.otf"